# Refresh Widget Dynamically in Android Studio

Tags: android, widget

I'm creating a prayer time app that shows five different times a day. I want to be able to refresh the widget if the user changes the city. The city is a spinner that has different times. How can I make it so that when the user changes the city, my widget will update?

Comment: I assume that "user changes the city" happens in an activity in your app. If so, after the user changes the city, use `AppWidgetManager` to update your app widget.

Comment: may I know how to do that? is it in the main activity or that certain activity?

Comment: "is it in the main activity or that certain activity?" -- it would be wherever your data changes. "may I know how to do that?" -- call `AppWidgetManager.getInstance(...)` to get an `AppWidgetManager` instance (where `...` is a `Context`). Then, call one of the `updateAppWidget()` methods on the `AppWidgetManager`, supplying the new `RemoteViews` to apply to your app widget.

Comment: I added the getInstance in the activity which after the city is changed, but I don't know where to put the updateAppWidget()?

Comment: Like what values am I supposed to put as the int?

Comment: That would be your app widget ID. You get this in `onUpdate()` in your `AppWidgetProvider`. You will need to track the outstanding app widget IDs and use those for your `updateAppWidget()` calls. Or, if you only really support one app widget at a time, use the `ComponentName` version of `updateAppWidget()` to say that you want to update all of your app widgets with the same content.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to make your widget a stateful one and use the `Onpressed` property of the button and have it change the state of widget.

The documentation for that is here : https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive

Comment: In this case, the question happens to be about Android app widgets, not Flutter widgets.